# Barycentric rational interpolation

Tags: c++, generics, lambda

I'm trying to write a function which returns a function for calculating Barycentric rational interpolation in C++.

Note:
It is not at all a wise idea to recalculate weight coefficients
W,  = 1, 2,…,  within the function itself that returns as a result of “Barycentric Interpolation”. Namely, in this way, these coefficients will be recalculated every time such a returned function is called, which is an unacceptable waste of time if it is large. Instead, these coefficients should be calculated within the “Barricentric Interpolation” function, placed somewhere, and “trapped” in the function that returns as a result. In this way, pre-calculated coefficients will be used for each call to the returned function, which is a great time saving

FORMULA:
[image]

EXAMPLE:

> for nodes: {{1, 3}, {2, 5}, {4, 4}, {5, 2}, {7, 1}}, and row=2
>
> `std::cout<<f(2.5)` would print 5.425

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <cmath>
int max(int a, int b)
{
  if (a > b)return a;
  return b;
}
int min(int a, int b)
{
  if (a < b)return a;
  return b;
}

std::vector<double> ComputeWeights(const std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>& nodes, int d) {
  std::vector<double>w;
  int n = nodes.size();
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    double sum = 0;
    int k = max(1, i - d);
    double product = product_f(k, k + d);
    for (int j = k; j < k + d; j++)
      sum += (pow(-1, k - 1) * 1. / (nodes[i].first - nodes[k].first));
    w.push_back(sum);
  }
  return w;
}

double ComputeF(double x, const std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>& nodes, const std::vector<double>& w) {
  double f, ff = 0;
  int n = nodes.size();
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    f = ((w[i] * nodes[i].second) / (x - nodes[i].first)) /
        (w[i] / (x - nodes[i].first));
    ff += f;
  }
  return ff;
}

std::function<double(double)> formula(std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>nodes, int d)
{
  if (d < 0 || d > nodes.size())
    throw std::domain_error("Forbidden row");
  int n = nodes.size();
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
      if (nodes[j].first == nodes[i].first)
        throw std::domain_error("Forbidden coordinates");
  auto w = ComputeWeights(nodes, d);
  return [nodes, w](double x) { return ComputeF(x, nodes, w); };
}
int main ()
{
  auto f = formula({{1, 3}, {2, 5}, {4, 4}, {5, 2}, {7, 1}}, 2);
  std::cout << f(2.5);
  return 0;
}
```

Could you help me to write this function properly?

My output is: **-nan** (correct is 5.425)

Comment: `sum_f(int i, int n)` never uses its parameter `i`. Was it supposed to? Same with `product_f`

Comment: `formula` is supposed to return a function taking `double` and returning `double`. Your lambda takes a `double` all right, but doesn't return anything. You probably meant it to `return ((sum_f...`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik loop should start with i in both functions, my mistake, I fixed it, thanks

Comment: You have a `return` statement within a `for` loop. That doesn't make any sense - on the first iteration of the loop, the `return` statement is encountered, and the function exits. The loop only ever runs one iteration; the lambda returned always captures `i==0`. I'm not sure I quite understand what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I guess you want to run a loop that calculates weights and puts them into a vector. Then, outside the loop, return a lambda that captures this vector of weights.

Comment: yes, on first iteration function exits. That is because I don't know how to calculate function, and after that how to return it as lambda

Comment: You can only pre-compute things that don't depend on `x` outside the lambda; such as `w`s. Anything that depends on `x` must necessarily go inside the lambda, which would have to run its own loops.

Comment: could you post a code example?

Comment: @RocketProcd  If you're concerned with speed, why not start with the low-hanging fruit, such as computing the sum of `n` consecutive integers without looping?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the best I knew I tried and posted

Comment: Then you are calling `sum_f` with the same parameters twice.  Then the same can be said of the product calculations.  You could have a table of precomputed factorial values and simply do a single division of two values in the table to get the result, i.e. `4x5x6 = 6! / 3!` --> `int answer4x5x6 = factTable[6] / factTable[4-1];`.  The point is that those sum and product "loops" in those functions could be eliminated altogether by using simple math.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie How could I use lambda for that?

Comment: Suppose you have a function `std::vector<double> ComputeWeights(const std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>& nodes, int d)` that computes `w`; and a function `double ComputeF(double x, const std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>& nodes, const std::vector<double>& w)` that computes `f` given nodes and pre-computed weights. Then `std::function<double(double)> formula(const std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>& nodes, int d) { auto w = ComputeWeights(nodes, d); return [nodes, w](double x) { return ComputeF(x, nodes, w); }` Implementing `ComputeWeights` and `ComputeF` is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I edited code based on you suggestion, now I get output as -nan, could you have a look what is the problem now?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik here's the problem https://godbolt.org/z/aqzhM4rMf

Comment: You are supposed to compute a sum of a certain expression, and a product of a certain expression. You call `sum_f` and `product_f` that merely compute "sum of `j` for `j` in range" and "product of `j` for `j` in range". No part of your code computes, for example, a product of `1/(x_j-x_i)` for `j` between `k` and `k+d`. The code doesn't resemble the formulas at all.

Comment: how? this supposed to do that:  `w.push_back(sum * pow(-1, k - 1) * product * 1. / (nodes[i].first - nodes[k].first));`

Comment: This doesn't do that. Obviously, it only uses two values `x_i` and `x_k`, but not `x_{k+1}`, `x_{k+2}`, ..., `x_{k+d}` that the formula calls fo. On these grounds alone it can't possibly be right. With all due respect, it appears you don't know what Sigma and Pi symbols mean in a formula; you may want to review this part in your math textbook.

Comment: sigma is sum, and capital pi is product, however, I don't understand that in the context of this task.. how this formula is applied is unclear to me. I wouldn't even knew to solve it on paper

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I posted math question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4451720/ could you explain in answer?

Comment: Given a formula `sum_{j=1}^n f(j)` , you seem to believe it means `(1 + 2 + ... + n) * f(1)` - that is incorrect. It means `f(1) + f(2) + ... + f(n)`. Similarly for a product - `product_{j=1}^n f(j)` is not `(1*2* ... *n) * f(1)`, but `f(1) * f(2) * ... * f(n)`. See also [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Capital-sigma_notation) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication#Product_of_a_sequence)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I edited code, now I think I follow correct approach, but result is -nan...

Comment: `ComputeWeights` calls `product_f` that is not declared. The code should fail to compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. Note that I rewrote basic parts of your code using my own code from the previous edit version. Further, to clarify: You are actually looking for a thing named Floater-Hormann approximation, which is basically an approximation by a rational function without poles in the interpolation region (and that is usually evaluated using the barycentric formula).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <cmath>


std::vector<double> ComputeWeights(const std::vector<std::pair<double, double>>& nodes, int d) {
    int n = (int)nodes.size();
    std::vector<double> w(n);
    for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k)
    {
        int imin = std::max(k - d, 0);
        int imax = std::min(n - d - 1,k);
        double temp = imin & 1 ? -1.0 : 1.0;
        double sum = 0.0;
        for (int i = imin; i <= imax; ++i)
        {
            int jmax = std::min(i + d, n - 1);
            double term = 1.0;
            for (int j = i; j <= jmax; ++j)
            {
                if (j == k) continue;
                term *= (nodes[k].first - nodes[j].first);
            }
            term = temp / term;
            temp = -temp;
            sum += term;
        }
        w[k] = sum;
    }
    return w;
}

double ComputeF(double x, const std::vector<std::pair<double, double>>& nodes, const std::vector<double>& w)
    {
        double num = 0.0;
        double denom = 0.0;

        for (int i = 0; i < (int)nodes.size(); ++i)
        {
            if (x == nodes[i].first)
            {
                return nodes[i].second;
            }

            auto ad = w[i] / (x - nodes[i].first);
            num += ad * nodes[i].second;
            denom += ad;
        }
        return num / denom;
    }

auto formula(std::vector<std::pair<double, double>>nodes, int d)
{
  if (d < 0 || d > (int)nodes.size())
    throw std::domain_error("Forbidden row");
  int n = nodes.size();
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
      if (nodes[j].first == nodes[i].first)
        throw std::domain_error("Forbidden coordinates");
  auto w = ComputeWeights(nodes, d);
  return [nodes, w](double x) { return ComputeF(x, nodes, w); };
}
```

Further, on the C++ level, note that I didn't use a `std::function`, but directly the lambda, which doesn't add any overhead by indirection. Moreover, I used a `std::pair<double, double>`, as we are usually in the floating-point regime when it comes to approximation.

The result is, as required

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<double, double> > nodes = {{1, 3}, {2, 5}, {4, 4}, {5, 2}, {7, 1}};

    auto f = formula(nodes,2);
    std::cout<<f(2.5)<<std::endl; //Prints 5.425
}
```

[DEMO](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bbd9e9d754c5d462)

Comment: thank you very much, but this is so complicated for me.  Could you make it simpler? I just need to apply given formula and make function which will return function. `std::cout<<f(2.5)` should print 5.425

Comment: Sure, I can simplify, it's your bounty. Note that what you basically want is Floater-Hormann interpolation, as your formula gives the corresponding set of weights. I'll let you know when I'm ready.

Comment: thanks, just make sure that `std::cout<<f(2.5)` prints 5.425. also, 200+ lines of code is too much for this.

Comment: See my edit. 200+ lines is not too much ... let's talk later when you want more, e.g. derivatives ;-)

Comment: thank you very much... super code and efficient

Comment: just one thing, could you write me here in comment this without ternary operators? `int imin = std::max(k - d, 0); int imax = k >= n - d ? n - d - 1 : k; double temp = imin & 1 ? -1 : 1;`

Comment: Sure, I'm like a consultant that is paid by SO point ... oh my ... there you go: `int imax = k; if(k >= n - d) { imax = n - d - 1; };` and `double temp = 1; if (imin % 2 == 1) {  temp = -1; }`. Note that `imin & 1` is equivalent to `imin % 2 == 1` and basically checks for odd numbers.

Comment: thank you very much, I'm suffering on this for days...

Comment: Then have fun, I'm glad to help. By the way -- can you say *why* you need this?

Comment: By the way: `imax` is better written as `int imax = std::min(n-d-1,k)`. I'll edit that in.

Comment: this is part of homework assignment, I could you send in private chat whole assignment, which is torture on students

Comment: hello, I'm trying to finish the second part of task, could you help me? https://pastebin.mozilla.org/OyLUw15a

Comment: I need to make approximation of this function...

Answer (score 0):

You forgot return keyword inside lambda body `return ((sum_f(1, n)...`

Comment: could you post whole line of code? Would that give correct output for f(2.5)?

Comment: here returned is missed: return [n, w, nodes, i](double x) {
      return ((sum_f(1, n)*w * nodes[i].second) / (x - nodes[i].first)) /
      (sum_f(1, n)*w / (x - nodes[i].first));
    };

Comment: But I think you need to work on formula implementation. The main formula f(x) uses two sums of expressions under that sum signs. It's not this sum  for (int j = i; j < n; j++)
    sum += j; 

As I understood your idea is to pre-calculate w-values. So you can firstly precalculate them for each i, save in vector and then use in another function where f(x) formula will be implemented, but w's won't be calculated each time, but used. 

And lambda won't be useful here.

Comment: thanks, could you post code example that would give correct output for `std::cout<<f(2.5)`?

Comment: I edited my code, I used your suggestion, but now my output is -nan, could you have a look now to see what is the problem?

Comment: here's the problem https://godbolt.org/z/aqzhM4rMf